# Cannot open my github pages on WeChat App (Android, iOS both)

Tags: browser, github-pages, wechat

I built [my website](https://aceshipping.github.io/) with github-pages. (Jekyll)

It opened well in web browser like chorme (pc, mobile both), Internet Explorer or something else.

But, the problem is that **it cannot be opened in Wechat App** (Android, iOS both). My access region is South-Korea (not china, for your information about chinese regulation)

(I am newbie on wechat and I don't know anything about Chinese online regulation. But I am sure that my blog is not blocked because I can access that blog on QQ browser)

### Detail information

[Imgur Image - Send URL to someone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwSe3.png)

1. I send URL to someone as above image.

[Imgur Image - No access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvmvm.png)

2. At first, It opened well. But second time clicking url again, It didn't open with **weird sentence** as above image.

> Tips. https://aceshipping.github.io 
>   For account security, do not enter any info related to WeChat password in the Internet.
>   Continue (button)

But, Continue Button doesn't work and also there is no private-related information required on my github page. (You know that there is no login feature available in github page)

Please help me. I need to open this on WeChat, without other browsers.

Comment: I found the chinese error "非微信官方网页，请确认是否继续访问。" Can you help me to get rid of this message? (I mean, without this message, access website)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? One friend encountered this message (really it's a block since you can't continue past it), but several other friends on wechat didn't see anything like this.

Comment: @mpoisot Well. I couldn't figure this out. Sorry not being helpful :(

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** use a .com/net/org/cn domain.

As of 2020/04, WeChat blocks links by default for public hosts like GitHub and Netlify, redirecting the page to `https://weixin110.qq.com/cgi-bin/mmspamsupport-bin/newredirectconfirmcgi?main_type=1&evil_type=100&source=2&url=<your link here>&scene=1&devicetype=android-28&exportkey=...&pass_ticket=...&wechat_real_lang=(en or zh_CN or something)`. This page is a normal redirection page indicating "非微信官方网页，请确认是否继续访问。" ("not a WeChat official web page, please confirm to continue browsing.") when the language of WeChat is Chinese (whether simplified or traditional), but on other languages it redirects to a link like `https://qbview.url.cn/getResourceInfo?appid=62&url=<your link here>&openid=<your WeChat account identifier>&version=10000&doview=1&platformtype=700`. This seems to be a removed Tencent service which serves the page with no JavaScript and reduced CSS ('safe browsing' / 'reader mode' as on redirection pages), which was removed on some date in 2019, now serving on a bad SSL certificate and returns only 400 (Bad Request). It seems that the Chinese version of the `weixin110` page is changed while in other languages the link remains unchanged, which leads to a bad link.

The HTML markup of those pages are listed, if anyone is interested: [en](https://codepen.io/alan-liang-the-vuer/pen/WNQwEzy), [zh_CN](https://codepen.io/alan-liang-the-vuer/pen/MWayvVx) (The words in the brackets are translations added by me)